# Get json data with file_get_contents

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

I need to retrieve the information from this url :

```
http://example.com/ajax.php?sport=soccer&language_id=vn&block_id=page_home_1_block_home_matches_1&block_name=block_home_matches&callback_params={"date": "2016-01-14", "display": "all"}&action=updateContent&params={}
```

With my url like this:

```
http://example.net/ajax.php?sport=soccer&language_id=vn&block_id=page_home_1_block_home_matches_1&block_name=block_home_matches&callback_params=%7B%22date%22%3A%20%222016-01-14%22%2C%20%22display%22%3A%20%22all%22%7D&action=updateContent&params=%7B%7D
```

Here is ajax.php :

```
<?php

$sport = $_GET["sport"];
$language_id = $_GET["language_id"];
$block_id = $_GET["block_id"];
$block_name = $_GET["block_name"];
$callback_params = $_GET["callback_params"];
$action = $_GET["action"];
$params = $_GET["params"];

$url = "http://example.com/ajax.php?sport=$sport&language_id=$language_id&block_id=$block_id&block_name=$block_name&callback_params=$callback_params&action=$action&amp;params=$params";

echo file_get_contents($url);

?>
```

But is return nothing, what wrong here ??

Comment: what is the result of var_dump(file_get_contents($url)); ?

Comment: @CooPer : boolean false

Comment: please check allow_url_fopen, if its true you have problem with url, you should print it and check where is the problem, for example you have `&amp` in your url, you must add `&` instead. test it step by step, without get parameter, check it with one parameter and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server might have `allow_url_fopen` set to Off for security (see http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)

Try using curl to get the data instead

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo $data;
```

Separately to avoid possible issues with the data you're passing in the URL, be sure to call urlencode on each variable in case any contain special characters such as `&` or `=`.  For example:

```
$sport = urlencode($_GET["sport"]);
```

Comment: Just edited my code to this, but it return **1** : http://pastebin.com/RqGmemhM

Here is original url : http://pastebin.com/Qg7RFGPw

Comment: @Tran Sorry I forgot the curl_exec line - I updated the answer - try now